# How do I create a script file for terminal commands that require sudo permissions

Tags: scripts, automation

my system keeps killing my wifi connection and I am having to use the terminal to restart it using the following comand

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

how would i write a script for this that I could place in my favorites bar

Comment: Seems like a workaround. The problem may be permanently fixable. Of course, it may not be, too.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.

Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I see your code there but fil to see where to and how to modify it for my system

Comment: The `net-o-matic.conf` file shows examples.